# php phalcon error:the image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: php, image, phalcon

[image]

firefox browser.

codes below:

[image]

[image]

the return value in function getQRcode is an image, i want to display it directly . then the erorr show in browser.

Comment: i put the image into file xxx.jpg. it shows correctly

Comment: i tried many ways, but it still don't work

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but I had to enable Digital Rights Management (DRM) content in firefox preferences to view imgur images.  Was getting the "image url cannot be displayed" error, after update to firefox 56.01 (64bit ubuntu)